# Android complex UI design

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I have requirement to implement complex UI design (Main scene for slot machine), so i am making research about the best way to do this. The main trouble as you can guess is dealing with different device sizes and densities. So as far i can see, i have two options initially:

1. Use standard android xml layouts. I tried to find some tutorials or examples how to deal with complex designs, but have not fount something that explains complex scenarios. Can you please refer to some article or maybe book, that teaches how to deal with this?
2. Use game framework. What are your recommendations about this, which framework is best for use nowadays?

Have in mind question is not related to animation, but only to implementation of UI.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of complex UI you want to design can you put some screens here.

[image]

You can design this ui using android default layout or you can draw it on canvas by your self.
To draw it on canvas you can refer [here android tutorials](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html) about drawing on canvas and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html).

But better aproach if you are trying to make any game is use game engine rather than doing designing in android canvas because later on when you put animation on it. It will definatly not look that much smooth as you want.
You can use "libgdx" or " unity2d" game engine for your work they have good support currently.

Comment: As i mentioned, i need to implement Slot Machine. For reference, it should look something like this:
http://www.androidtapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/SlotSpot-Gameplay-550x343.png